# CSS animation overlapping div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to animate a scrolling text (in a paragraph) so that it will move from the bottom to the top of a div, scroll out of the div (become invisible) and then loop. Here is the relevant css:

```
@keyframes showAndScroll {
            0% {opacity: 0;}
            10% {opacity: 0.85;}
            50% {opacity: 0.85;}
            60% {opacity: 0;}
            100% {opacity: 0;}

        }

        .infobar {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 30%;
            bottom: 0%;
            color: white;
            background-color: red;
            opacity: 0.75;
            text-indent: 30px;
            font-size: 200%;


            pointer-events: none;

            animation-name: showAndScroll;
            animation-duration: 40s;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        }

        @keyframes scroll {
            0% {
                transform: translateY(600%); color: red;
                }
            50% {
                transform: translateY(-200%); color: blue;
                }
        }

        .infobar p {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: inline-block;
            animation-name: scroll;
            animation-duration: 40s;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-timing-function: linear;
        }
```

And the html code:

```
<div class="infobar">
        <p>
            Infobar test
        <p>
    </div>
```

I'm having two issues:

1. The text overlaps the rest of the document. How can I make the paragraph invisible as it hits the edge of its parent div? This effect is what I'm looking for: http://media02.hongkiat.com/marquee-css3-animation//demo/index2.html
2. For some reason, placing the paragraph at 100% of the div doesn't seem to put it on the "bottom" of the div (I've currently placed it at 600%). Why is this?

Any input is appreciated. Here is my JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/essi/oqh6ok00/1/

Comment: youre translating the `p` tag from 600% to -200%, of course it will push beyond the boundary and overlap the parent container. try putting 0 instead of -200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to class `.infobar`. In this way the overflow is clipped, and your animated element will be visible within edges similarly to what you have shown us in your link example.

```css
@keyframes showAndScroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0.85;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.85;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.infobar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  bottom: 0%;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.75;
  text-indent: 30px;
  font-size: 200%;
  pointer-events: none;
  animation-name: showAndScroll;
  animation-duration: 40s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(600%);
    color: red;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-200%);
    color: blue;
  }
}

.infobar p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  animation-name: scroll;
  animation-duration: 40s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="infobar">
  <p>
    Infobar test
    <p>
</div>
```